# Cannot find module 'rxjs' or its corresponding type declarations, after switching to rxjs 7

Tags: rxjs, stackblitz

I'm facing this strange error after I have switched from rxjs 6.5 to rxjs 7. I'm not sure if it's a issue with the typings for rxjs 7 or if it's a issue with stackblitz (https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-20-21-obs):

[image: error on stacblitz]

Comment: Interesting. If I put in a package name of `rxjs@7.0.0-rc.3`, then it seems to work. Not sure why.

Comment: From Eric Simons (CEO of Stackblitz) on twitter: "We’re on it- upstream issue from Monaco not supporting latest version of typescript :( Should have a fix out either tomorrow or next week. Compilation / serving should still work tho!"

Comment: @DeborahK this explains also why the compilation works fine. I should follow Eric on twitter :)

Answer (score 0):

This should only happen while using stackblitz and not a real life project after rc.3

It is happening due to the recent changes and the major RXJS upgrade from version 6 to 7.

If you upgrade your **Typescript version** something **greater than 4.2.x**, you shouldn't face the issue in a real life project.

Right now it's still a pinned issue on github: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/6350

I made a Q&A in this post as well because it effects the Angular framework as well: [Cannot find module 'rxjs' or its corresponding type declarations.(2307) using stackblitz](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68591147/5706293)