# Cannot find module 'rxjs' or its corresponding type declarations.(2307) using Angular stackblitz

Tags: angular, rxjs, codepen, stackblitz

While using stackblitz with an Angular 12 - rxjs 7 project. I'm getting this error while trying to import a `Subject`:

> Cannot find module 'rxjs' or its corresponding type declarations.(2307)

[image]

Am I using a wrong version of typescript?

[Error stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xwavof?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening due to the recent changes and the major RXJS upgrade from version 6 to 7.

If you upgrade your **Typescript version** something **greater than `4.2.x`**, you shouldn't face the issue in a real life project. However, the error will still be there for now on stackblitz and codepen projects that use rxjs@7 for now.

Right now it's still a pinned issue on github: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/6350